# How to call a certain code only once per day in bash script?

Tags: bash

I am working on a project in Controlled Environmental Agriculture. I am done with most of the sensors coding. I even wrote a bash script to call each of the sensors code at the needed time. Now coming to the RPi NOIR camera code and OpenCV code, the problem I have with this is, it needs to be executed only once per day. The RPi camera code captures an image. Next the control must go to the OpenCV code and get completely executed. Once these both are done, the rest  of the code needs to get executed.

I tried giving a upper and lower limit to the time and executing it within that much time. You can see below.

```
    now=$(date + "%T") // This checks out what time it is. 
if [ $now -gt 9:58:59 -a $now -lt 10:01:00 ]
then
    python camera.py //This code captures an image
            sleep 30s
            python cv.py //this is the CV code which performs edge 
                         detection and area detection on the crops
    else
            sleep 5s
    python interrupt.py 1
        cat test_data.txt
        python ph_test.py
        cat line.txt
        sleep 10s
        python temphumi.py
        cat dht.txt
        python dht_test.py
        cat line.txt
        sleep 10s
        python watertemp.py
        cat water_sensor.txt
        python water_test.py
        cat line.txt
        sleep 10s
        python interrupt.py 2
        cat test_data.txt
        python ec_test.py
        cat line.txt
fi
```

done

I just want the camera.py and cv.py in the if part to get executed once and else part at anytime the rest of the day.

Comment: Would a cron job do what you need? A cron job is a command that gets run automatically at a certain time interval, in your case every day at 10 o'clock. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/2368/22015) explains how to set one up.

Comment: @legoscia Thank you so much for your help! I went through these cron jobs as you mentioned and executed a few samples as shown in youtube videos too. But I am  not able to figure out how to apply it in my case. Could you please help me out

Comment: I posted an answer that shows how to run the script once a day.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is removing the code that checks the time from your script, and then use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to schedule it to run once a day at 10 in the morning.  Run `crontab -e` to edit the "crontab" (the file that lists jobs to execute regularly), and add this line:

```
0 10 * * * /path/to/my-script
```

Replace `/path/to/script` to point to where your script is.  Ensure that the script is executable (`chmod +x my-script`).

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me, sorry for the miscommunication on my part. I wanted to execute only the python camera.py code once a day which captures an image of my crop, and then the image is sent as input to my CV code and after the analysis is done by the CV code the rest of the bash script in the else part should run for the rest of the day until the next day 10 am.

Comment: Only the camera and CV code should run once a day, after that control should go to the rest of it.